# Can't backup postgres database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When trying to backup a postgres db in the pgAdmin UI it's throwing an error with no reason given in the processes panel
[image]
[image]

So I then tried to do a pg_dump in the administrator cmd with this command

`pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 -d landlords -f dump_file.sql`

and I get these errors

[image]
[image]

So then I tried installing an earlier version of Postgres (15) and I got the same error.
I'm on Windows 10

Comment: When you run from the command line, what was the path used?  What version of pgadmin4 is in use?